# IE computed css style

Tags: css, internet-explorer

How can I find the source for some CSS styles being applied to my page in IE8? Specifically, my `<legend>` is orange and has a size of about 1px unless I set a style on it (even on the `<fieldset>` doesn't work)

**EDIT :**
Here is an example to show what I mean. The markup is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>test1</legend>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the result in my IE8 is

[image]

If you look closely you can see the tiny orange spec that is the legend.

**EDIT 2:**
I just noticed that the fieldset has round corners. Is this odd, or am I wrong and this is how fieldsets look in IE?

Answer (score 1):

Hit f12 and you will get the developer tools.  Click the arrow button and then click on the element in question.  You will get a list of all styles applied to the element and where they are coming from.

The tricky part about background though is that you could have a transparent background on your element and one of its ancestors may have the background color.  So you may need to traverse the tree.

Comment: It is not background, it is foreground. Where in this do I get the styles? All I can find is the styles applied by my style sheets, not the ones applied by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOM inspector of [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

Comment: How can you use this to find the origin of a css rule?

Comment: @baruch yep. See [this image](http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/latest/screenshots/firebug1.3-img04.png).

Comment: That doesn't give the browser's default rules.

Comment: @baruch I think no. But to avoid problems with the styles applied by the browser, why not use a [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)?